# Create log files for each date in separate directory with current system date

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

I am trying to save logs of my spring-boot application for each date in a different directory with the current date, month and year.

I have tried using timestamps it stores the logs in the separate directory only if we restart the tomcat server every day.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="org.mongodb" level="ERROR" />

    <property name="DIRECTORY" value="/home/Properties/logs" />

    <timestamp key="year" datePattern="yyyy" />
    <timestamp key="month" datePattern="MM" />
    <timestamp key="date" datePattern="dd" />
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss}][%-5p][%C][%t][%L]%m%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${DIRECTORY}/${year}/${month}/${date}/logfile.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss}][%-5p][%C][%t][%L]%m%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I want my logs for each date to be stored in a directory created every day without the need of restarting the server in the manner similar as [year]\[month]\[date]\logfile.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution to my own question, if any of you find a better solution please let me know.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="DIRECTORY" value="/home/Properties/logs" />
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss}][%-5p][%C][%t][%L]%m%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DIRECTORY}/logfile.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DIRECTORY}/%d{yyyy/MM/dd, aux}/logfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss}][%-5p][%C][%t][%L]%m%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `RollingFileAppender` in conjunction with `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`, And set `fileNamePattern` to `%d{yyyy/MM/dd}/logFile.log`. See [this link](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) for more details

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>%d{yyyy/MM/dd}/logFile.log</fileNamePattern>

      <!-- keep 30 days worth of history capped at 3GB total size -->
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
      <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>

    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender> 

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have tried the same as well but it is also not working, in this scenario as well it needs the server restart.

Comment: RollingFileAppender with TimeBasedRollingPolicy does not require server restart after configured completed.

Comment: Yeah jacky the file is rolling but in same directory on the date when server was started.

Comment: If you want to keep different date log on different directories, use `<fileNamePattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd}/logFile.log</fileNamePattern>` instead

Comment: it is making the directory as %d{yyyy-MM-dd}

Comment: is there a way by which we can make the timestamp dynamic I think it may also solve my problem

Comment: `%d{yyyy/MM/dd}/log_file.log` is what you want?

Comment: I want to have a separate directory with the year as its name under this directory I want month as a directory and within it, there should be a directory with the current date as its name and under the date directory my logfiles must be placed and all of these should be generated dynamically without the need of restarting the server, cause as of now I have to restart the server daily to achieve such directory structure.

Comment: RollingFileAppender  `FileNamePattern` with `%d{yyyy/MM/dd}/log_file.log` is what you want, And I also updated the answer

Comment: I only need year say %d{yyyy}/log_file.log, but its not working

Comment: TimeBasedRollingPolicy does not support yearly rollover, at least monthly